# Cannot implement Comparable

Tags: java, android, extend, comparable

I'm trying to sort my list of passes with some help of the Comparable interface but I fail horribly.

```
public class Pass extends JSONBase implements Comparable<Pass>{

}
```

This line raises the next error in Android Studio:

```
'java.lang.Comparable' cannot be inherited with different type arguments: 
'com.dendrowen.oveasy.model.JSONBase' and 'com.dendrowen.oveasy.model.Pass'
```

I'm afraid the answer is obvious but I just don't see it! (I of course do know I need the `compareTo()` method)

Comment: The problem is exactly what it says. `JSONBase` already implements `Comparable<JSONBase>`. You can't reimplement it with different type arguments.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I... I just feel stupid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'java.lang.Comparable' cannot be inherited with different type arguments:
'com.dendrowen.oveasy.model.JSONBase' and 'com.dendrowen.oveasy.model.Pass
```

It's an error which describes the problem in detail. It says:

```
The Interface 'java.lang.Comparable' cannot be inherited with different type arguments
You're trying to inherite it with type JSONBase and Pass.
```

It means that JSONBase already implements it and there is no possibility to implement it again. You can `@Override` the appropriate method in `Pass.java`